# How to resolve NoReverseMatch in Django

Tags: python, django, web

guys, I am having this error when I try to login to my Django web app

**NoReverseMatch at /login/
Reverse for 'blog-home' not found. 'blog-home' is not a valid view function or pattern name.**

Here are the app urls.py codes

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import (PostListView, PostCreateView,
                    PostUpdateView, PostDetailView, PostDeleteView, UserPostListView)
from . import views

app_name = 'posts'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', PostListView.as_view(), name="blog-home"),
    path('user/<str:username>/', UserPostListView.as_view(), name="user-posts"),
    path('post/<int:pk>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name="post-detail"),
    path('post/new/', PostCreateView.as_view(), name="post-create"),
    path('post/<int:pk>/update', PostUpdateView.as_view(), name="post-update"),
    path('post/<int:pk>/delete', PostDeleteView.as_view(), name="post-delete"),
    path('about/', views.about, name="blog-about"),

]
```

Here also is the login template code in a separate app called users

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="content-section">
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Log In</legend>
                {{ form|crispy }}
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Login</button>
                <small class="text-muted ml-2">
                    <a href="{% url 'password_reset' %}">Forgot Password?</a>
                </small>
            </div>
        </form>
        <div class="border-top pt-3">
            <small class="text-muted">
                Need An Account? <a class="ml-2" href="{% url 'register' %}">Sign Up</a>
            </small>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Below is the project urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from users import views as user_view

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('register/', user_view.register, name="register"),
    path('profile/', user_view.profile, name="profile"),
    path('groups/', include("groups.urls", namespace="groups")),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html'), name="login"),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='users/logout.html'), name="logout"),
    path('password-reset/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name='users/password_reset.html'), name="password_reset"),
    path('password-reset/done/', auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(template_name='users/password_reset_done.html'), name="password_reset_done"),
    path('password-reset-confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/', auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(template_name='users/password_reset_confirm.html'), name="password_reset_confirm"),
    path('password-reset-complete/', auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(template_name='users/password_reset_complete.html'), name="password_reset_complete"),
    path('', include("blog.urls")),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: So it your app named "blog" or "posts"? And I don't see any attempts to revers `"blog-home"` in given template, perhaps it's in the base template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've added an `app_name` of 'posts' to your urls.py file. That means you need to use the URL name 'posts:blog-home". See the [Django docs about url namespaces](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces-and-included-urlconfs). Oh, and it's very likely that this false reference to 'blog-home' is actually in your base template "blog/base.html", which you extend from (but will still cause errors when you try to go to the login page, as the html from the base template is pulled in then).